# Update database to Drupal 6 to Drupal 7

Tags: database, migrations

I upgraded my website to D6 to D7 successful but only with the development version (not in production) and I've new datas in production since (Drupal 6). So I'm wondering the best way for update the Drupal 6 database to the Drupal 7 database.

Answer (score 0):

You could migrate DB data with the [Migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) (though it's not very light module and has an individual learning curve, so if you are not a programmer, or not yet, it might be better for you to find a Drupal programmer that will help you run it). Otherwise, if the site is small (i.e has only several or about fifteen pages) I would suggest of building it from the start... In most cases it shouldn't take much time..

Blessings,

Comment: I do the migration (with pain), after the migration I have lot of inconsistency in the database so I was forced to update some tables with SQL queries but it's done, my Drupal 7 website work but it's the development version and my client added new contents in production (so with Drupal 6) and now, I'm wondering if I needed to use SQL queries again or if a other way is possible?

Comment: If the client didn't add much content tell him to stop adding content so that no further inconsistencies would be made, and ask him to re-adding these content pieces after you will finish to migrate. I think it would be the best solution. In the worst case, hire a Migration veteran programmer for all the small details...